# In Mercurial, "hg rename" works but the history doesn't follow the file?

Tags: mercurial

I remember in SVN, I can rename a file from foo.txt to foo2.txt and all the history will follow (log file of foo2.txt will show all history of foo.txt as well).  But on Mercurial, seems like that's not the case.  When a `hg rename` is done, then `hg log foo2.txt` will not show any previous history of `foo.txt`?  Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `hg log --follow foo2.txt` or `hg log -f foo2.txt` (short form) to show you the entire history of the file before the `hg rename`

Comment: Also xanatos [described](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5264567/501399) how you can change the default `log` command behaviour to `--follow`.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand this answer. If I apply the `log` command BEFORE the `hg rename` then there is no `foo2.txt`. If I apply if after, there is no `foo.txt`, and `foo2.txt` has no history. Also how will mercurial "know" that the file `foo2.txt` is the new version of `foo.txt`?

Comment: @mg30rg the answer does not say that you should run `hg log -f` before you rename. It merely says that, `hg log -f` shows you the history before the file was renamed.