# Why 'hg mv' (mercurial) doesn't move a file's history by default?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I know [how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472216/in-mercurial-hg-rename-works-but-the-history-doesnt-follow-the-file), I just can't understand why `hg mv` doesn't move the file's history as well by default.

It really seems silly to be obligated me to run `hg log --follow` before `hg mv`. This remembers me the times with cvs when you needed to remove and add a file using two different operations and losing history in the same way.

IMHO, if I were just using builtin mv that would be ok to lose history, but I'm using `hg mv`, and, thinking about the repository itself, it doesn't make sense to lose the history `by default`. There should be `hg mv --no-follow` and not the other way round.

This isn't intuitive. Anyone here has a sane explanation about this behavior? Is this an error by design, or there's really a good reason for it? Is it possible to do this `--follow` by default someway when using `hg mv`?

Comment: `hg log --follow` has no effect on the results of `hg mv`.  There is no reason  or obligation to run `log` before `mv`,  (In the future, the `--follow` flag will help you look at logs _after_ you have renamed files in your repository with `hg mv`.  That's all it's for.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can can change the default behaviour of log: in your ~/.hgrc (or somewhere/Mercurial.ini), add

```
[alias] 
log = log -f
```

I've read the appearance of the log is for speed reason. Move isn't truly a "first level" operation in Mercurial. It's a copy + delete (this compared to Bazaar where the move/rename is a "first level" operation but that doesn't have a copy with history preservation).

Comment: @xanatos: Is it possible to create a hook or something that, before doing hg mv, it automatically runs hg log -f?

Comment: No no. The hg log -f only shows the log. The mv is ALWAYS saved as a cp + rm (the same for rename if I remember correctly). You are only forcing the log to work a little more to follow the history of the files.

Comment: @xanatos, mv is just an alias for rename.

Comment: @Matthew I suspected it, but I wasn't sure 100%. As an added note, at least on Windows, the graphical interface will show the full log of a copied file (right key on a file, TortoiseHG, Revision History)

Comment: @xanatos (hg dev here): it is FUD from Mark S. that it is more a first level operation in bazaar than in hg. They behave in the same way, it's just that for historical and performance reason we don't follow by default for log (but we **do** for merges). (Note that Git is actually different from hg and bzr, since it recomputes it every time, both approaches have their merits).

Comment: @tonfa Considering that bzr doesn't have a cp command (and that is the reason I'm now using hg instead of bzr), I fail to see how they could do a cp+rm for a mv :-) ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+bug/269095 )

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen and @xanatos: Now I got it. In fact, everything makes sense, having the --follow option actually makes more sense than not having it.

Comment: CAUTION: adding log -f alias to your .hgrc breaks the Mercurial log tab in IntelliJ. See [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-212220).

Answer (score 34):

You don't know how to do it.  `hg log --follow` affects how the log is displayed, not how the actual move is done.  By default, the history of the filename is displayed.  `--follow` follows renames and copies.  This fits with how Mercurial is internally implemented.

There is no reason whatsoever to run `hg log --follow` before `hg mv`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @xantos is now dated. The proper way to update the **hgrc** file is:

```
[alias]
log = log -f
```

Comment: CAUTION: adding log -f alias to your .hgrc breaks the Mercurial log tab in IntelliJ. See [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-212220).