# Hg: How to move files (to subfolder) without losing history?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

How to move files (to subfolder) without losing their history?

In my Mercurial repository (I mean the folder with the .hg in it) I have MyProject/ folder with all project files. Now I need to create src/ folder inside and move all files to it (from **MyProject/** to **MyProject/src/**). How can I do it without losing all history?

Comment: Where do you want repository root to be after move? In `MyProject/` or  `MyProject/src/`?

Comment: @black_wizard It's not about repository root. It should remain where it is. MyProject is NOT repository root. It is a folder in the repository. I just want to create one more subfolder inside this folder and move files.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
hg mv
```

does do the right thing, but `hg log` does not list entries past the move unless you
give it the `-f` option. See this question for more info

[Why 'hg mv' (mercurial) doesn't move a file's history by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264528/why-hg-mv-mercurial-doesnt-move-a-files-history-by-default)

After you do this, you likely want to add the `-f` option to `hg log`
to the hgrc file for the repo.

```
.hg/hgrc

[defaults] 
log = -f
```

Comment: Is it possible to hg mv all files from the directory? Or only one by one? I tried "hg mv MyProject/ MyProject/src/" but it is not exactly what I want. It moves the MyProject folder to the src, so MyProject/src/MyProject/ instead of just moving all files from the MyProject/ to the src/

Answer (score 50):

Since you have a "tortoisehg" tag, I figured I'd explain the way I do this using the GUI.

Usually, I just rename/move files in my IDE, or from windows explorer, then when I go to commit, THG will show a bunch of (?) unknown files and (R) removed files. Just right click on any of the files and choose "Detect Renames...", then click the "Find Renames" button.

You might have to adjust the "Min Similarity" slider until you get all the files you want and only the files you want, but it's usually very straightforward.

Comment: That just saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 13):

In Windows with Tortoise HG installed, there is a windows shell extension that handles this very nicely.

In Windows Explorer, simply right-click and drag the file(s) you wish to move into the destination folder. You are then presented with a pop-up that give you these choices:

**HG Move versioned item(s) here**

**HG Copy versioned item(s) here**

Comment: If you, like me, are running TortoiseHG on a virtualised Windows on a MacBook, this won't work - in this case however you can use Rename..., which also lets you change directories, not just the filename itself.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It moves/copies the file but the history is lost.

Answer (score 5):

Use `hg mv` to move your files and then use `hg log -f` (follow) to see history including renames.