# How to get hg vdiff to follow renamed/moved files?

Tags: mercurial, vimdiff

I use vimdiff as the diff tool in Mercurial. When I diff a renamed or moved file, it treats the file as new instead of comparing it with the old one. Is there a way to fix that?

Here's my .hgrc:

```
[extensions]
hgext.extdiff =

[extdiff]
cmd.vimdiff =
```

I invoke it with

```
hg vimdiff <filename>
```

Comment: Not sure if it will resolve this issue, but generally using -f will tell hg to "follow" renames. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045248/hg-how-to-move-files-to-subfolder-without-losing-history/22055830#22055830

Comment: Yep, I already have `hg diff` following renames. This doesn't seem to get picked up by vimdiff, though.