# File History for Renamed Files in TortoiseHg

Tags: file-io, mercurial, history, tortoisehg, hgrc

I know how to use Mercurial to rename a file. And I understand that the `hg log` command does not display file history prior to renaming the file unless you use the `-f` option, and also that you can force the file history to be displayed as described in the accepted answer here [Why 'hg mv' (mercurial) doesn't move a file's history by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264528/why-hg-mv-mercurial-doesnt-move-a-files-history-by-default)

However, when I rename a file, and then check the File History using TortoiseHg, I am unable to view the full history of the file including any changes prior to renaming the file, even though I updated my **~/.hgrc** file to include those changes as explanined in the aforementioned link. How can I do that? How can I force File History to include changes that happened to the file prior to renaming the file, and display that history list on TortoisHg?

---

### UPDATE

TertoiseHg version 3.1 shows the full history. I had version 2.8 that did now show the history.

Thanks to Lazy Badger for his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Linked answer is outdated (partially, at least in part of existing section `[default]` - now it's `[alias]`)
- I see **full** history of renamed file in TortoiseHG without any additional tricks (TortoiseHg version 3.0.2)

[image: History of renames]

Comment: Thanks. I think I know why I had a problem. My TertoiseHg was version 2.8. I updated to the latest after reading your answer, version 3.1, and File History shows all the changes. Thanks.