# Mercurial: How to move a project/module, but keep the revision history

Tags: java, mercurial, move, revision-history

Consider the following multi-module project (within a single repository):

```
Module A (i.e. parent)
  - Module 1 (various core stuff)
    - Module i
  - Module 2 (non-core, depends on 1)
    - Module ii
    - Module iii
```

(The reason for a set up like this is it enables some developers to just work on individual modules (e.g. `2` and its children), whilst other developers can work on the whole code base (e.g. `A` and its children).

Let us then suppose that `Module ii` has been reclassified as `core`, and needs to be moved into `Module 1`.

I could just handle this by moving `Module ii` from `Module 2` to `Module 1`. However, mercurial treats this as a delete (from `2`) and add (in `1`), and thus we would lose the revision history from `ii` prior to the move. (I know that we would not actually 'lose' this, as it would still be available in mercurial; however, it would not be readily accessible wrt the files in the new location).

How can I move files and have mercurial move the revision history with those files?

Comment: This isn't very clear. Are these modules separate repos? Are you asking how to combine repositories whilst preserving history?

Comment: As you can see in [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264528/why-hg-mv-mercurial-doesnt-move-a-files-history-by-default) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472216/in-mercurial-hg-rename-works-but-the-history-doesnt-follow-the-file), the history can still be accessed even though it is done with a copy and then a delete.  This assumes that the top of your mercurial repository is Module A.

Comment: @PaulS - I don't understand where your questions are coming from; they seem to be suggesting a level of complexity that is not implied in the question. For superfluous clarification, I have edited the question to confirm that this is all in a single repository...

Comment: @amaidment It's quite common in mercurial to have different 'modules' of a system in different repositories. I was thinking there must have been something special about the situation to warrant the question. If it's all in one repo then the answer is `hg mv`, which `hg help` would have told you.

Comment: Mercurial does treat a move as a copy + delete, preserving all history, and this is rather trivial (does not show research effort, hence -1). Like SVN, you need to use `hg mv` to perform the copy (or mark it as such after the fact), otherwise it is not aware that the file has moved.

Comment: @101100 - thanks for the links, those were helpful for working this out. However, they're not very helpfully tagged - could you (or someone else...) add tags of 'move' 'hg mv' 'revision-history' for these questions? (I would do this, but lack the rep to do so...)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to convert these add/remove pairs to "renames" using `hg mv`, as long as they remain in the same repository.

Answer (score 1):

The info is there and is not lost.  You just need to use the **-f,--follow** flag for hg log.
(This is what @freixo points to in post [Why 'hg mv' (mercurial) doesn't move a file's history by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264528/why-hg-mv-mercurial-doesnt-move-a-files-history-by-default))

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change your ~/.hgrc (or Mercurial.ini) doing what xanatos says here: [Why 'hg mv' (mercurial) doesn't move a file's history by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264528/why-hg-mv-mercurial-doesnt-move-a-files-history-by-default)